# UIScrolview Prioritize vertical and horizontal scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've a scenario where I am using a list of views that scrolls horizontally, like pagination. And each view has tableviews which scrolls vertically. Now the issue is when I want to scroll vertically. It hardly allows me to do that. But vertically it's fine. Can I arrange this in a way that vertically scrolling should have higher priority than horizontal? But both should be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have an `UIScrollView` for horizontal scroll and couple of `UITableView`s inside as pages? I think your issue lays in the `UIScrollView` which intercepts vertical pan gesture. Try to disable vertical scrolling for your `UIScrollView` and it should help.

Comment: I'm using tableview for pagination. It's vertical scrolling is disabled. but point is I'm unable to scroll inner pages properly in vertical direction.

Comment: Hmm.. Why (and how) are you using `UITableView` for horizontal pagination? It's better to use pure `UIScrollView` I think...

Comment: ok. Switched to scroll view. Now if I have list in inner tableview. It scrolls down. But Unable to show egorefreshview. Why is this?

Comment: Don't know what's wrong with EGORefreshView. When I've tried it I was disappoint in this control a bit and switched to MNMPullToRefresh.
Can't suggest much without some code shown...

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 5, `UIScrollView` exposes its `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Set your custom swipe’s delegate to self and make the `gestureRecognizer` a property or ivar, and make your class conform to the `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` protocol.

Then, implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`’s – `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`: like so:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isEqual:self.swipe] && [otherGestureRecognizer isEqual:self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer])
      {
         return NO;
      }
     return YES; //default
 }
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit more? how do I manage swipe and gesture recognizer?